# How to cache Parcelable model on recyclerview

Tags: java, android, api, caching, android-recyclerview

I've a `recyclerview` list of a `Parcelable` model.

Model's data comes from an API (using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)). And I want to be able to cache the data, and the user can click on a button to refresh the data (clear up the cached data).

Answer (score 0):

It depends for how long you want to store data. If only for while, when app is active you can just store it in your recyclerview adapter. If you want to store it for use after another run you can store it in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) or database by [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) or [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html)

Comment: How can I store it in the `recyclerview` adapter? Thanks

Comment: You should provide some code. How and where you create your recyclerview adapter?